# Is there a DOM Inspector like Chromes for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-addon, dom-inspector

I really dislike Firefox DOM Inspector. Is there one that docks to the page so I don't have two separate windows and also highlights the box/margins/padding like Chrome/Safari does? I can't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of Firefox have it built in. Here is how to open it:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (Windows)
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (OSX)

**References**

- [Firefox Tool Shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_tools)

Answer (score 1):

Firebug is the best tool for web development missions:
http://getfirebug.com/

Once you get used to it, there is also a (Lite) version for Chrome:
http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/